# Initializing a reference variable in a class constructor

Tags: c++, reference

So I'm still kind of figuring out the semantics of C++ references here.

I have a class that has a reference as a member, and I initialize the reference in the constructor.

```
template<class T>
class AVLNode {

private:
       T & data;
public:
       AVLNode(T & newData) {
            data = newData;
        }
};
```

But I get this error on the constructor line:

```
error: uninitialized reference member ‘AVLNode<int>::data’ [-fpermissive]
```

I don't get this, I initialize the reference as soon as the class is constructed so there shouldn't be a problem with the reference being uninitialized right?

Comment: You don't initialize it, you assign to it.

Comment: not a duplicate, the answer provided to my question included a clear definition of initializer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since `data` is a reference, you must initialize it at constructor initializer:

```
AVLNode(T & newData): data(newData) {

}
```

You may find this post useful: [reference member variable must be initialized at constructor initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890438/reference-varable-with-error-must-be-initialized-in-constructor-base-member-ini). You may also need to understand the difference between **`initialization`** and **`assignment`** when you write a class's constructor.

Quoting from C++ Primer pp455:

> Some members must be initialized in the constructor initializer. For such members, assigning to them in the constructor body doesn't work. Members of a class type that do not have default constructor and members that are **const or reference types must be initialized in the constructor initializer regardless of type.**

Comment: Very interesting. That works! My C++ book actually doesn't touch on these at all! THanks for your help

Comment: If it actually doesn't mention member initialization list, burn that book.

Comment: Damn you know I almost bought C++ Primer...but I bought C++ Primer Plus instead -_-

Comment: if it mentions it...it isn't listed in the index...